# Map Form Fields with Model Fields in Django

Tags: python, django

I am new to django and trying to create a simple form. I am using django 3.1.2 and python 3.8.3.

Below is my code
**model**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    categoryid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'category'

    def __str__(self):
        return u'{0}'.format(self.name)


class Timesheet(models.Model):
    timesheetid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    categoryid = models.ForeignKey(Category, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='categoryid')
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
    logdate = models.DateField()
    minutes = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    addeddate = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
    modifieddate = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'timesheet'
```

**form**

```
class TimesheetForm(forms.ModelForm):
    categoryid = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all().order_by('name'),
                                                         empty_label="Select Category",required=True,label='Category',to_field_name='categoryid')
    class Meta:
        model = Timesheet
        fields = ['summary','description','logdate','minutes']
```

**view**

```
def fill_timesheet(request):
    form = TimesheetForm()

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TimesheetForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print(form.cleaned_data['summary'])
            print(form.cleaned_data['description'])
            print(form.cleaned_data['categoryid'])
            form.save(commit=True)
            return index(request)
        else:
            print('ERROR FORM INVALID')

    return render(request,'app_timesheet/timesheet.html',{'timesheet_form':form})
```

Below is my web page
[image]

I am getting below error whenever try to save data

```
null value in column "categoryid" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (32, null, test data, test description, 2020-10-13, 5, 2020-10-15 14:25:40.57836, null).
```

also, `print(form.cleaned_data['categoryid'])` statement of fill_timesheet view is printing category name instead of categoryid.
My question is how can I link categoryid of form with categoryid of model. I want to show drop down of category on web page and want to insert categoryid in table.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because you are not including `categoryid` in your **`Meta.fields`** of the `TimesheetForm` class

```
 
class TimesheetForm(forms.ModelForm):
    categoryid = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all().order_by('name'),
                                                         empty_label="Select Category",required=True,label='Category',to_field_name='categoryid')
    class Meta:
        model = Timesheet
        fields = ['summary','description','logdate','minutes','categoryid']
```

Comment: it worked after adding categoryid in fields list. I thought we dont need to add fields which are defined separately.